# AngularJs: transclude through include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to make the directive with dynamic template

```
app.directive('boolInput', function () {
  'use strict';

  var
    restrict = 'E',
    replace = true,
    template = '<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>',
    scope = {
        value: "=",
        template: "@"
    },
    link = function (scope, element, attributes) {
        // some stuff
    };

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: restrict,
    replace: replace,
    template: template,
    scope: scope,
    transclude: true
  };
});
```

So I use

```
template = '<ng-include src="template"></ng-include>'
```

and

```
scope = {
        //..
        template: "@"
    }
```

to pass template url via attribute. All work great instead of one thing. There is how I use directive:

```
<bool-input data-value="item.value" data-ng-repeat="item in source" data-  template="templates/boolInput.html">
    {{item.Text}}
</bool-input>

{{item.Text}} - should be transcluded into template
```

That template:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox-custom" ng-transclude>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <i class="icon-unchecked checked"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

but this does not happen, as a result I see:

```
<ng-include src="template" data-value="item.value" data-ng-repeat="item in data" data-template="templates/boolInput.html" class="ng-scope"><div class="checkbox ng-scope">
    <label class="checkbox-custom" ng-transclude="">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <i class="icon-unchecked checked"></i>
        <!-- There should be the text -->
    </label>
</div></ng-include>
```

Comment: did you try templateUrl instead of template and include?

Comment: with templateUrl all work well, but it`s not a way to dynamic template

Comment: Think you have to have ng-include directly in your template.

Comment: Ryo, if you mean separate html file with the same content as in my "template", so that not work too

Answer (score 0):

This was 2 years ago... For now we can pass a attribute to templateUrl function

`templateUrl: function (elememt, attrs) { 
     return attrs.template || '<some default template path>';
 }`